# How to re-enable FTP on secondary Ubuntu/Debian server to pull updates from Main Linux Server with Mirrored depository?

Tags: apt, server, updates, ftp, 19.10

updated both my Linux servers to Ubuntu 19.10 and the latest version of Debian which both are pointing to my main Linux Server running a Mirrored depository and allows communications to it via FTP, and now I am receiving message stating

```
The method 'ftp' is unsupported and disabled by default. 
Consider switching to http(s). 
Set Dir::Bin::Methods::ftp to "ftp" to enable it again.
```

after failing to fetch `ftp://`. How can I re-enable the retrieval of system update via FTP?

Comment: You may also want to simply update your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to use http/https protocol instead of ftp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On the command line run

```
echo 'Dir::Bin::Methods::ftp "ftp";' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99local-ftp
```

This will create a config file named `99local-ftp` (you may choose another name if you want) in folder `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` that contains the line

```
Dir::Bin::Methods::ftp "ftp"
```

This will re-enable FTP for apt.

Comment: Wow! thank you Sir, you are the man, fixed my issue on all three of my Linux Servers.